# Swift - Using a closure inside a repeat loop

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, closures, capture

I am trying to implement a user registration system and I need to know whether a user id (generated randomly) has already been assigned to another user or not. To do so, I connect my Firebase database and use the `observer()` method to check to availability of the generated id.

However, since the Firebase database query runs asynchronously and I can only know the result once the query returns, I am not able to use the correct return value from within the calling method.

My approach here is

```
repeat {
  id = generateUniqueId()
  check availability
} while (id is not unique)
```

The implementation I have is

```
var id:String
var test = true
repeat {
    id = generateId()
    ref.child("\(databaseReferenceName)").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        test = snapshot.hasChild("\(id)")
    }
} while (test == true)
```

This loop keeps running even though the `test` variable is set to `false` by the `hasChild()` method.

How can I change the code so that I would be able to capture the right value of the `test` variable?

I am using Swift 4.1

Thanks

Comment: You can't use a repeat loop. You need to invoke your next attempt from the closure.

Comment: You need to indicate which framework you're using.

Comment: Never `while` this way. That's horrible.

Comment: @vadian, you should explain why using `while` like this is horrible. While loops, in and of themselves, are ok. The problem is using a while loop to try to respond to an async function.

Comment: @DuncanC OK, more specific: A `while` loop to **poll something** 100000 times a second is horrible. *Don't ask, tell*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the process is asynchronous the  loop will run until hit the first `test = false` , but i think you need this recursive way until find an available id

```
func checkID() {

       id = generateId()
       ref.child("\(databaseReferenceName)").observeSingleEvent(.value) { (snapshot) in
         let test = snapshot.hasChild("\(id)")

         if test {
           print("id exists")
           checkID() // check another one
         }
         else {
          print("this is the one \(id)")
         }
       }

}
```

another thing is that it should be `observeSingleEvent` instead of `observe`

Comment: You beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't say, but I'm assuming the observe() function you're using is asynchronous, and will return before the work is done. As PaulW11 says, you need to trigger the next round in the completion handler:

```
func observeChildren() {
    var id:String
        id = generateId()
        ref.child("\(databaseReferenceName)").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChild("\(id)") {
              observeChildren() //recursively call observeChildren again.
        }
}
```